# How to create a TCP server using Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp, sails.js

So I'm using [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/#/), and when I run `sails lift` it works properly in serving the website.  However, how can I create a TCP server that also runs when I `sails lift` and constantly listens for raw TCP messages from clients?  I have found this simple TCP server example for Node.js (which obviously will work for Sails):

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
    socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

How can I integrate this into Sails?  Do I need to modify the `app.js` file (which is what I presume gets run when `sails lift` is entered)?  Any ideas?

Comment: use [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/) module.

Comment: I have previously tried that, and unfortunately it doesn't do what I want.  I'm trying to interface with a device that sends and receives raw TCP messages, which `socket.io` doesn't do.  However,  I have had success with Node.js `net` module as a client, so I know that the server side of the `net` module would work, just not sure as to how I integrate it into my Sails.js server running on `sails lift`.

Comment: You should try `socket.io v0.9`. I have build many apps for devices using it.

Comment: If I were to give `socket.io` a try, where I would I place the TCP server code so that it runs this server when I run `sails lift`?

Comment: refer [this](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/167)

Comment: That issues shows how to set up a `socket.io` TCP client connection with clientside Javascript - I need to set up a TCP server with server side Javascript, hence the necessity of the TCP server running after entering the `sails lift` command, which starts up a normal Sails server.

Comment: refer [this](http://socket.io/docs/)

Comment: That is useful, thanks.  However, I'm working with the prebuilt `app.js` that comes with Sails, and I don't think just throwing TCP server code in that file is going to make it work.  Someone more familiar with Sails than I am might know.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer, because it's not complete, but I think you can accomplish this by using a hook. You can create a hook in `/api/hooks` and sails should automatically load it. The API is in flux and there's no documentation on the site, but you can find some info [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/tree/master/lib/hooks). The socket implementation is a hook, actually, so you might be able to glean something by looking at the `sockets/` directory in that repo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little bit late to the party, but recently i had the same requirement and came up with the following code:

```
let net = require('net');

net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        const req = {
            url: '/controllername/method',
            method: 'get'
        };

        const res = {
            _clientCallback: function _clientCallback(clientRes) {
                // TODO: do something useful with clientRes
                message = clientRes.body;
                if (clientRes.body && clientRes.body.message) {
                    message = clientRes.body.message;
                }
                process.stdout.write(message);
            }
        }

        sails.router.route(req, res);
    });
}).listen(1338);
```

Have a look at the project [sails-hook-sockets](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-hook-sockets/blob/d436e410c3c1e6d5bb309edd7874964eefaa46dd/lib/receive-incoming-sails-io-msg.js#L83-L241) too.